# unrecognized characters while pasting tags from facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code in javascript to send the comment via ajax to a JSP file :

```
comment=encodeURIComponent(comment);
alert(comment);
$('mydiv').load('/SendComment.jsp?productId='+productId+'&comment='+comment);
```

I use `encodeURIComponent` because my comment can contain multiple lines, single quotes, double quotes etc which break the URL in the `load` call, when sent as it is.

When a user copy-pastes a tag from facebook (eg: ***#Egypt***), the `encodeURIComponent` converts it to

```
%23%E2%80%8EEgypt%E2%80%AC
```

and when i later print that comment, it comes as:

```
â€ŽEgyptâ€¬
```

This problem doesnt happen when I manually type '#Egypt' which encodes to `%23Egypt`

How do I solve this?

Comment: looks like your SendComment.jsp script doesn't know how to treat it like UTF-8.

Comment: No, those characters are inserted before the ajax call is made. I have mentioned the difference I see between a pasted tag and manually writing '#Egypt'

Comment: The character encoded by E2808E is Unicode 200E, the left-to-right mark character. Clearly, that character is present in the source material from which "#Egypt" is being copied, or else the user agent is prepending that character to the copy buffer.

Comment: These are characters in UTF that help the browser know the direction of the text. `E2 80 8E` is UTF for LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK (&lrm;) and `E2 80 AC` means POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING (which is to end the bidirectional string)

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky yes I missed a couple of bits :) The point is that the characters are there in the source of the copy-paste, probably a right-to-left context (like Arabic).